# Cosine similarity with synonyms

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have some words which are synonyms that I would like to consider similar to the original word. For instance, word `restaurant` and `bar` are considered synonyms in this example.

To apply cosine similarity under this scenario, I decided to keep the same word in both vectors, but if one word is considered synonym then I subtract a "penalty" to the counter. In this scenario, I have to compare the original v1=['cafe'] against v2=['restaurant']. Then, I have the following:

```
v1=Counter({'cafe': 1})
v2=Counter({'cafe': 0.65}) #0.65 because word restaurant is synonym
```

However, if I apply this strategy, I ended up with similarity 1.0 (0.65/0.65). I need to get a similarity below 1.0 because restaurant is not considered the same word, but is synonym.

I implemented cosine similarity in the following way:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])
    
    sum1 = sum([vec1[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec1.keys())])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec2.keys())])
    
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator
   
v1=Counter({'cafe': 1})
v2=Counter({'cafe': 0.65})
print(get_cosine(v1, v2))
```

How can I get similarity in synonyms? while keeping the control on which words are considered synonyms. Currently, I am getting those synonyms from database.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** compute the **cosine similarity**, using **similarity ratio** (0.65, 1), we compute cosine similarity between two words to get the following ratio (i.e. **0.65**), for example, and it's done by **counting common characters** as an initial step, therefore it's going to be more **mathematically convenient** to treat this ratio as a **probability**, and in case of you need a **smooth version** of the probability, then you might use function such **negative entropy**, it's might be more accurate to use (or **model**) some **extended value function.**